# Perfect formula for window-size based font size?

Tags: css, font-size, calc

Recently I've discovered this site: https://varagon.com/

They are using some interesting calc formula for calculating window size based font size. Formula is as following:

```
font-size: calc(22px + 54 * ((53vw + 53vh) - 600px) / 820);
```

For screen dimensions 1920x1126 px computed font-size value is 88.8006px.
Could you explain what every value in formula is for?

EDIT:

Maybe I didn't express my question properly - I know what VH and VW are, my question is about whole calc formula. Ie. why are they adding 22px to sum of half of heigh and width, etc. :)
I tried to reverse engineer/math it, unsuccessfully for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found possible answer - this formula is some kind of 'vmax' polyfill (as for lack of IE11 support for this value).

Polyfill that I found looks very similar formula I was asking about:
https://gist.github.com/uto-usui/ea9836aa92d334e7694fb31d8e93a4f4

Answer (score 1):

In the site, they have used **Viewport-percentage lengths.** 
To read about this [click here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

---

The values are:

- vw (1% of the initial containing block width)
- vh (1% of the initial containing block height)
- vi (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's inline axis)
- vb (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's block axis)
- vmin (the smaller of vw or vh)
- vmax (the larger or vw or vh)

---

> If we take a vw, if the width of the viewport is 200mm, the font size
>   of h1 elements will be 16mm (i.e. (8×200mm)/100).
>
> **h1 { font-size: 8vw }**

From this, we can see that, when the viewport width increases the font-size increases.

*The font-size of the website has been calculated from the above-mentioned concept.*

Comment: Thank you for response! I know what VH and VW are - my question was about whole formula inside calc(). I corrected question.